# Plotting a 3D vector for a perceptron

Tags: vectors, graphing-functions

I am trying to plot a 3D vector for a perceptron but I am getting different results from what my professor gave me.

My vector is:

$w_0 = 0.2$
$w_1 = 1$
$w_2 = -1$

My data points:

$Class_{+1} = {(0.08, 0.72), (0.26, 0.58), (0.45, 0.15), (0.60, 0.30)}$
$Class_{-1}: {(0.10, 1.00), (0.35, 0.95), (0.70, 0.65), (0.92, 0.45)}$

My graph comes out like this (using MATLAB):

[image]

However, the graph my professor gave me a looks like this:

[image]

The **initial line** is graphed by the following equation: $0.2 + 1i_1 – 1i_2 = 0$ (In the first graph $x$ is $i_1$ and $y$ is $i_2$). From what I see, $-1i_2$ is being ignored, but I don't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.